# Constructor cannot be applied to given types for constructor with arguments

Tags: java

```
package com.coolsite.example;

public class SavingsAccount {
    // instance fields
    double balance = 100;
    String accountholder;

    // class constructor
    public void SavingsAccount(String bankname, String account) {
        System.out.println("Thank you, " + account + ", for creating a new saving account with " + bankname + "!");
        accountholder = account;
    }

    // methods

    //..snip..
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Bank Software!");
        String bankname = "The Bank Bank";
        String user = "User1";
        SavingsAccount savings1 = new SavingsAccount(bankname, user);
        savings1.deposit(44);
        savings1.withdraw(5);
        savings1.checkBalance();

    }
}
```

When run I receive the error `java: constructor cannot be applied to given types`. There is only one class in the package, and the types when creating the instance seem to be correct.

**EDIT**: From the future, yes; this quite a noob question that could be, and has been solved by reading the docs.

Comment: "*`public void SavingsAccount(String bankname, String account) {`*" - This is not a constructor. Remove the `void` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has its root cause in this line of code:

```
public class SavingsAccount {
    ...
    // class constructor
    public void SavingsAccount(String bankname, String account) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is not a constructor. A constructor has no return type, the return type is automatically inferred through the class name.

To solve the problem, it is sufficient to remove the `void`-keyword from `SavingsAccount(...)`.

I recommend reading a tutorial on constructors, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 1):

A constructor **does not** have a return type.